# Pressing EFI Boot for Proxmox loads Mac OS X 10.6.8

Tags: mac-mini, proxmox

I have a usb stick with Proxmox VE ISO 7.1 burnt to it.  The USB stick successfully installed proxmox to some PC machines, so I thought I'd use it on a Mac Mini generation 2,1. Here's what I did:

1. I plugged the USB stick into the mac mini.
2. I turn on the mac mini and immediately press ALT key on my keyboard
3. I see a screen with 2 icons: MainVolume and EFI Boot
4. I choose EFI Boot with my mouse and press the left mouse button.

Result: I see Mac OS X 10.6.8

What do I need to do differently to make the Result be that I see the Proxmox installation process like the way I see it when installing for PC machines?

---

Note: I've also tried formatting the USB stick and some Mac Journal formatting before using a mac bash terminal to use `convert` and `dd` to convert an `iso` to `dmg` to a bootable usb stick.  This still resulted in the same outcomes and results as the steps above.  So no matter how I make the USB, choosing EFI Boot still only loads MAC OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Were the PCs where you were able to boot from it UEFI and the boot mode also UEFI, not Legacy?

Comment: A Mini 2,1 would be a Core2 Duo 2007 iirc… Getting anything older than 2009 to boot from USB is quite a task - one I never succeeded in doing on an 08 Mac Pro in all the time I've had it …14 years :\ If you have any newer Mac test the stick works, just so you know it's the pre-09 issue you're definitely facing. You could see if a specific bless works - https://superuser.com/questions/436745/cant-boot-off-usb-drive-in-os-x-10-6-8